# Alternative to push_back for 'new' dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am required to use the keyword 'new' to create a dynamic array (part of learning purpose). The program will read a text file and then extract each line and put it into the array. I have done it successfully for the vector method but I can't see how to change the method to make it work with 'new'.

This is my vector method:

```
...

vector <string> placeholder;

while(getline(filename, linedata))
{
    placeholder.push_back(linedata);
}

...
```

I have declared a new variable

```
string * placeholder1 = new String[5];
```

I can't figure out how to alter push_back to push my linedata to this placeholder1. Any idea?

Note: No vector solution as I already got the vector part working.

Comment: What is `String`? Is is different from `string` or just things like `typedef`?

Comment: A `std::vector` needs three things: Its current *capacity* (the current amount of allocated elements), its *size* (the current number of elements), and a pointer to the allocated data. Right now you only have the capacity (`5`) and the pointer (`placeholder1`). Now think about the size and how you could use ot to know where to "push back" elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a counter variable and use it for selecting elements to use.

```
string * placeholder1 = new String[5];

int pos = 0;
while(getline(filename, linedata))
{
    if (pos < 5) placeholder1[pos++] = linedata;
}
```

or

```
string * placeholder1 = new String[5];

int pos = 0;
while(pos < 5 && getline(filename, placeholder1[pos]))
{
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the ++ all along.